# Unable to Redirect No route in the routing table matches the supplied values. in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Unable to Redirect to some to a page showing error "No route in the routing table matches the supplied values. in MVC 5 "

```
 [Route("Job")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    // Redirect 
 [Route("Job/Logout")]
    public ActionResult logout() {
                return RedirectToAction("Job");
    }
```

Comment: If your global routing is set up correctly,  your end-points will answer on http://localhost:XXXX/Job and http://localhost:XXXX/logout. Correct? And your problem is?

Comment: My problem is when i redirect to "Job" Action Method Is Shows error "No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

Comment: And exactly how to do you test this? I need to know in order to help you.

Comment: [link](https://ji.conveyor.cloud/job)  this is site it has a logout link when i click "logout()" action method call  after that I am getting this error  . I Hope This can help more you to understand my error

Comment: I don't know how to say this in a different way, so here we go, don't do testing in production environment.  Please describe your problem thoroughly in your question and include all necessary info. We need to be able to run your code on our computers. OK?

Comment: I also don't understand how I describe my error briefly, I almost show the backend code to you that when I run this logout method through my view page with help of anchor tag it shows that error and unable to route to the page. I am running my code on my computer. ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219994/discussion-between-aditya-gupta-and-roar-s).

Comment: Maybe another day, it is late where I am, and I'm been working for like 40 hours. I'm sure there are other people here that can help you. BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing your route attribute value to `RedirectToAction`. Instead you need the name of your `ActionResult` which in this case is Index.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```